# Facebook JS API, accessing public photos without authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am looking to know is there a way to get a listing of photos in a specific album on a specific page (where both the album and page are public).  Without the need to authenticate at a user level.  I basically am looking to show a number of photos from an organisations page on that organisations website (however I dont want to show them all).

I have followed the examples here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
and here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album/photos

but I cant appear to get a listing of photos.  Is it possible to get such a listing without the user authenticating with FB first?

Comment: No, the user must authenticate first.

Comment: no, the user does not have to authorize your app. it´s about a page, not a user profile.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can use an **App Access Token** if the Page is not restricted by age or location, or a **Page Access Token** if the Page is restricted. **App Tokens** and **Extended Page Tokens** are valid forever, so you can just store those on your server to make the API calls. No additional user authorization needed.

Information about how to generate the different Tokens can be found here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/